# mockMvc POST Junit test failing with HttpMessageNotReadableException

Tags: java, spring, rest, jackson

I am trying to do a JUNIT test for a post request I have created in a controller. While GET succeeds, POST does not.

```
public class SampleObject implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String name;
    public SampleObject(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Sample post request

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/post", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces="application/json", consumes="application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public SampleObject postActiveSource(@RequestBody SampleObject inputObject) {
        return inputObject;
    }
```

And here is my mock test.

```
public class MockMvcHtmlUnitCreateMessageTest {


MockMvc mockMvc;

@InjectMocks
SampleController controller; 

 @Before
  public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    this.mockMvc = standaloneSetup(controller)
            .setMessageConverters(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter()).build();
  }

@Test
public void test() {

    SampleObject so = controller.new SampleObject("abcd");
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();


    try {
        this.mockMvc.perform(post("/service/sample/post").content(mapper.writeValueAsString(so)).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andDo(print());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }

}
```

I get the this exception.

```
Resolved Exception:
          Type = org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException
```

However, a get request works fine. What is going wrong here? Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit1:**

I noticed the following exception. This might help.

```
nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class com..rest.controller.SampleController$SampleObject]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: org.springframework.mock.web.DelegatingServletInputStream@c792d4; line: 1, column: 2]
```

**Edit2:**

Based on [a suggestion below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26123262/592748), I changed modified the constructor,

```
public SampleObject(@JsonProperty("name") String name) {
            this.name = name;
}
```

however, I get the following exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument #0 of constructor [constructor for SampleController$SampleObject, annotations: [null]] has no property name annotation; must have name when multiple-paramater constructor annotated as Creator at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory.findValueInstantia‌​tor(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:287) ~[jackson-databind-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
```

Comment: That is a very weird error in your 2nd edit and I can't reproduce it. Try recompiling.

Comment: Yes, my bad. It can see it now. It's working! However, I put the SampleObject as a separate class. It was defined within the Controller. I am not sure if the error had anything to do with that.

Comment: Do I remove the edit no. 2? How does it work?

Comment: No, you can leave it for _historical_ reasons. If you the class inside another, it was an inner class. That's a whole other story for deserialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jackson expects a parameterless constructor for your POJO classes by default. If you need to have a parameterized constructor, you'll need to annotated its parameters.

```
public SampleObject(@JsonProperty("name") String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have to configure `MessageConverter` in your config file.  If you use Java Configuration:

```
 protected void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);

        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        jacksonConverter.setObjectMapper(mapper);

        converters.add(jacksonConverter);
    }
```

Comment: I placed your code in setUp but the same error. I have added another exception that I noticed. Probably that throws some light?

Comment: It has to be in the configuration. If you use Java Configuration, you can use the code.

Comment: Oh, what configuration is that?